# Как вырезать нужные строки из файла, если в паттерне 10000 строк?

Tags: grep

Хочу вырезать строки из файла содержащие нужные мне значения

попробовал так:

```
$ grep -f что.найти.txt файл.в.котором.найти.txt > result.txt
```

но т.к строк которых надо найти около 10к , то процесс длится очень долго и заканчивается сообщение о нехватке RAM

как правильно заменить в команде кусок `что.найти.txt` куском с перечислением всего того что нужно найти,
что то наподобе:  `$ grep -f слово1,слово2,слово3,слово4...слово10000 файл.в.котором.найти.txt > result.txt`

что бы машина не обращалась каждый раз к файлу а взяла все из строки

Comment: написать то можно. Но поможет ли оно - вряд ли. Писать если что, нужно так `git 'word\|word2\|word3' file.txt`. То есть, слова разделяются вертикальной черточкой, но ее нужно эскейпить (если конечно у вас не свой специфичный терминал).

Comment: не знаю, почему  в комментари выше написал git, а не grep. Если в файле с строками только строки (то есть, нет регулярок), то можно попробовать использовать fgrep. Он будет работать немного быстрее.

Comment: а если слова которые искать содержат  "/" , то как правильно написать? там слова вида /123456/

Comment: эксейпить слешом. Но я думаю, что Вам нужно хорошо посмотреть на список и "ужать его".

Comment: Попробуй через массив: !/bin/bash

for word in $(cat file_with.words.txt)
do 
  grep $word file.txt > result.txt
done